# How to update all document fields except specified ones in mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I present a simple model:

```
public class UserDocument
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public List<string> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the latest C# driver which has the ability to replace a document using a C# object which will automatically update *all its fields*. Problem is I want to update *all fields except for the user friends*, because it's a field containing the object relations to other documents. Of course I can manually update each field of the ones I want to get updated, which here are just two.

But this example is simple just to make my point. In reality the fields are much more and it would be harder to update each field. That would require a single line for each one to use the `Set` operator. Also, newly-added fields would have to be supported in the same way as opposed to updating to automatically just works.

Is there a way to achieve that - automatically update all fields with just specifying a list of excluded fields?

Comment: I came across a similar case with a similar requirement to what you described .. can share how you solved it ?

Comment: I can't remember a solution different from the approaches in my question or in the answer of @i3arnon, otherwise I would have posted it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way, using the provided builders to have a "blacklist" update which excludes only specific fields.

You can query the old document, copy the old values of these fields to the new instance and then replace it entirely in the database.

You can also generate such an update command by iterating over the fields using reflection.

But the MongoDB driver **doesn't offer such a query** built in.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do this with MongoDB using Javascript/NodeJS, but maybe the logic can translate to C#?

I wanted to update all fields without having to actually explicitly state them (all fields except for one, it turned out).

**Attempted update of all document fields:**

```
await examCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: new ObjectID(this.examId)},
  {$set: this.data}
)
```

...except, `this.data` happened to have `_id` in it as well, which I didn't want to update. (In fact, it gave me an error, because `_id` is immutable.)

So, for my workaround, I ended up "deleting" all fields on the object that I didn't want to update (i.e. `_id`).

**Successful update of all *non-specified* document fields:**

```
// (1) specify fields that I don't want updated (aka get rid of them from object) (similar option in C#?)
delete this.data._id 
//delete this.data.anotherField
//delete this.data.anotherField2
//delete this.data.anotherField3
    
// (2) update MongoDB document
await examCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: new ObjectID(this.examId)},
  {$set: this.data}
)
```

This was much easier than explicitly stating all the fields I *did* want to update, because there were A LOT, and they could potentially change in the future (new fields added, fields deleted, etc.).

Hopefully this strategy can help!

*Note:  In reality, I did my "field specifying" earlier in another file, rather than immediately before updating like it shows in the example, but same effect.*